# Calcular el promedio de varios campos POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Estoy intentando calcular el promedio de varios campos, algunos están ordenados de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la primera fila tiene 6 campos del **asin "B0746FWLTR"** y el otro tiene 7 y asi sucesivamente de manera incremental , la tabla por defecto cuando va un dato vacio le pone un valor en CERO (0) por lo cual supongo yo que al hacer un AVG() no se sumarian estos valores en 0 hasta el momento he hecho algo asi

```
select asin, round((avg(campo1)+
avg(campo2)+
avg(campo3)+
avg(campo4)+
avg(campo5)+
avg(campo6)+
avg(campo7))/150)  as Average from rating Group by asin
```

lo divido por 150 ya que es el total de campos que contiene la tabla , como no conozco el valor exacto de columnas es decir
Ejemplo:

```
      asin        total columnas
    B0746FWLTR    6 
    B0746F2PCS    7
```

O de que manera podría hacerlo así?

También he intentado con

```
 select campo , count(*) from (
    SELECT campor1 campo from rating 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT campo2 campo from rating
)v1
    group by campo
```

Alguna sugerencia de como hacer esto?

Comment: Cuando diices 150 campos, quieres decir que tienes campo1 a campo150? ¿Cómo buscas calcular el promedio? de forma horizontal, por fila? de forma vertical por columna?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si de campo 1 a campo150. creo que no es la mejor practica, pero es lo que se me ha ocurrido o si me puede orientar mejor para hacerlo... busco calcular el promedio sumando los campos y el resultado insertarlo en otra tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tienes organizados los datos, y mediante SQL estándar me temo que la solución va a ser algo larga de escribir. Para obtener el total, simplemente sumamos cada columna, los valores 0 serán irrelevantes en el total, el problema es como saber la cantidad, la única forma es determinar si el campo no es 0, en cuyo caso sumamos 1:

```
SELECT asin,
       SUM(campo1 + campo2 + ... campo150) as total,
       sum(CASE WHEN campo1 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN campo2 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           ...
           CASE WHEN campo150 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Cantidad
       from rating 
       Group by asin;
```

Con esta consulta, obtenemos un Total y una Cantidad por asin, lo que resta es simplemente dividir ambos datos para obtener el promedio:

```
SELECT asin,
       CASE WHEN Cantidad = 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE ROUND(CAST(Total as numeric(15,2)) / Cantidad,2) 
       END as Promedio
       FROM (SELECT  asin,
                     SUM(campo1 + campo2 + ... campo150) as total,
                     sum(CASE WHEN campo1 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                         CASE WHEN campo2 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                         ...
                         CASE WHEN campo150 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Cantidad
                     from rating 
                     Group by asin
       ) T;
```

Comment: Gracias...! de esta manera funciona justo lo que estaba tratando de hacer.... solo tengo un detalle puse todos los campos y ejecuta perfecto, pero cuando la ejecuto dentro de la sub consulta para sacar el promedio, me devuelve "Division por Cero"

Comment: Seguramente alguna Cantidad retorna 0, de ahí la división por 0.  Agregué el control de esta situación en mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: Esta perfecto. Gracias!